# What does getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mean?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the aws-sdk/client-applicationcostprofiler so I could import data from S3 to cost profiler. But I keep getting the error

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND application-cost-profiler.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

This is what I did..

imported package:

```
const { ApplicationCostProfilerClient, ListReportDefinitionsCommand, ImportApplicationUsageCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-applicationcostprofiler");
```

the rest of the code:

```
const clientCP = new ApplicationCostProfilerClient({region: env.region});

const paramsCP = {
  "sourceS3Location": {
    "bucket": env.bucketname,
    "key": env.key,
    "region": env.region
  }
}

const CommandCP = new ImportApplicationUsageCommand(paramsCP);
const dataCP = await clientCP.send(CommandCP);
```

Comment: Which AWS JS SDK are you using? Where does `ApplicationCostProfilerClient` come from? Surely there's more code than this

Comment: its from the package I imported it from. The package @aws-sdk/client-applicationcostprofiler

Comment: Cheers, so it's [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-applicationcostprofiler/index.html).

Comment: The value comes from [this file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/v3.137.0/clients/client-applicationcostprofiler/src/endpoints.ts#L36). You might need to [raise a bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/new/choose) with them since that address doesn't seem to exist for any region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this buried deep in [some documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/application-cost-profiler/latest/userguide/app-cost-profiler-ug.pdf)...

> #### Service endpoints
>
> Application Cost Profiler is a global service. All API calls must be made to the US East (N. Virginia)
> endpoint.
>
> - US East (N. Virginia) – `application-cost-profiler.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Ignore your `env.region` and use a hard-coded `us-east-1`...

```js
const clientCP = new ApplicationCostProfilerClient({region: "us-east-1"});
```

I'd still [raise an issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/new/choose) with the AWS team since [their own code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/v3.137.0/clients/client-applicationcostprofiler/src/endpoints.ts#L36) just doesn't make sense...

> ```js
> hostname: "application-cost-profiler.{region}.amazonaws.com",
> ```